# Disk file creation error with Vbox and vagrant

Tags: debian, vagrant, virtualbox, disk, diskimage

### Objective

Create a VM with Vagrant and Virtualbox with 2 disks for setting a raid1 later.

### My Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "debian/buster64"

  disco1 = 'disco1.vdi'
  disco2 = 'disco2.vdi'

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # Create disk files if they haven't been created
    if not File.exists?(disco1)
      vb.customize ['createhd', '--filename', disco1, '--variant', 'Fixed', '--size', 10 * 1024]
    end
    if not File.exists?(disco2)
      vb.customize ['createhd', '--filename', disco2, '--variant', 'Fixed', '--size', 10 * 1024]

      # Add SATA controller with 4 ports
      vb.customize ['storagectl', :id, '--name', 'SATAController', '--add', 'sata', '--portcount', 4]

      # Attach the disks to the SATA controller
      vb.customize ['storageattach', :id,  '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disco1]
      vb.customize ['storageattach', :id,  '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 2, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', disco2]
    end
  end


end
```

### Showing directory tree

```
.
|-- Vagrantfile
`-- Vagrantfile.b

0 directories, 2 files
```

I have created a directory for this scenario, and I show you the output of a `tree -a` so you can see that all is alright.

### Error I get after `vagrant up`

I'll show you the complete output, so you can see the whole process + error

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'debian/buster64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: scenario_raid1_default_1569617045977_67208
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
A customization command failed:

["createhd", "--filename", "disco1.vdi", "--variant", "Fixed", "--size", 10240]

The following error was experienced:

#<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["createhd", "--filename", "disco1.vdi", "--variant", "Fixed", "--size", "10240"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create medium
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the medium storage unit '/home/atlas/Documents/vagrant/scenario_raid1/disco1.vdi'.
VBoxManage: error: VDI: cannot create image '/home/atlas/Documents/vagrant/scenario_raid1/disco1.vdi' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreateMedium(HandlerArg*)" at line 462 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
>

Please fix this customization and try again.
```

I can't understand why I get this error, if as you can see, I deleted all the files again from previous creations with errors.
**BUT** there is something funny happening. If after getting this error, I execute `tree -a` again, look what I get:

```
.
|-- .vagrant
|   |-- machines
|   |   `-- default
|   |       `-- virtualbox
|   |           |-- action_set_name
|   |           |-- creator_uid
|   |           |-- id
|   |           |-- index_uuid
|   |           `-- vagrant_cwd
|   `-- rgloader
|       `-- loader.rb
|-- Vagrantfile
|-- Vagrantfile.b
`-- disco1.vdi

5 directories, 9 files
```

As you can notice, one of the 2 disks have been created (but I'm pretty sure this is not working because the Sata controller and the link to the SATA controller has not been executed).
I'm pretty sure **this** is a big clue of what it's happening here, but I can't see how can I solve this situation.